# How should I design a user blocking system?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I've created little social website which has user generated content in it. And users should have option to block each other if they don't like what they post.

So I'm using postgresql and I have three simple tables.

```
Table User
id (pk)  | user_name
1       | a
2       | b
3       | c

Table Post
id (pk)  | user_id (fk)
1       | 1
2       | 3
3       | 2
4       | 2

Table Block
id (pk) | blocker_id (fk)  | blocked_id (fk)
1       | 1              | 2
2       | 2              | 1
```

Btw, as you can see, I use two-way block because I don't want that if user1 blocks user2, user2 shouldn't see user1's posts too.

I wrote an sql:

```
SELECT * FROM Post p INNER JOIN Block b
ON p.user_id = b.blocker_id
WHERE b.blocked_id <> @current_user_id
```

But what if user hasn't blocked anyone? This sql doesn't cover that case and it only shows user's posts that has record on the **block** table.

#### What I expect:

- For user1, this sql should return user3's and user1's posts.
- For user2, it should return user3's and user2's posts.
- For user3, it should return **every users** posts.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: The database design looks fine to me. User 1 can block user 2, while user 2 may still want to see user 1's posts.

Comment: Although I misunderstood A blocks B to only mean A doesn't want to see B's posts, while it turns out it shall also mean A doesn't want B to see A's Posts, the database design is still correct :-) In your example user1 blocks user2 and user2 blocks user1, too. Even if one user would withdraw their blocking, it wouldn't change anything; they would both have to withdraw their blockings, so they can see each other's posts again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I think your idea of making the blocking symmetrical is wrong. Imagine the case when user1 blocks user2, which would create two blocks in your case, in both directions. What if user1 decides to unblock user2? In that case you will need to remove two records. Yet, what if both of them would like to block each-other? In this case you will have two records as well. So unblocking becomes ambivalent. My suggestion is to create a single record when user1 blocks user2 and search for both blocker_id and blocked_id, so checking who cannot see whose post would look like this:

```
select *
from User
join Block
on User.id = Block.blocker_id or User.id = Block.blocked_id
```

Now, let's see your query. You do not need to join with Block, instead you will need to check whether exists a Block record:

```
select *
from Post p
where p.user_id = @current_user_id and
      not exists (select id
                  from Block
                  where Block.blocker_id = p.user_id or Block.blocked_id = p.user_id)
```

Note, that I did not work much with PostgreSQL (but a lot with SQL in general), so if I have some syntax errors, then it can be attributed to my noobness in PostgreSQL.

EDIT

The solution is the code below:

```
select *
from Post p
where
not exists (select id
from Block
where ((Block.blocked_id = p.user_id) and (Block.blocker_id = @current_user_id)) or ((Block.blocked_id = @current_user_id) and (Block.blocker_id = p.user_id))
```

Explanation: We need to find block records where either the current user is blocking the author or the author is blocking the current user.

Comment: I suppose (and hope) that you have merely misunderstood what "I use two-way block because I don't want that if user1 blocks user2, user2 shouldn't see user1's posts too" was supposed to mean. Your queries are correct. Pure Standard SQL that will run in about every DBMS.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner actually I did not misunderstand it. I pointed out in my answer the concern that storing two records, blocking the active user by the passive user automatically is bad design in my opinion. I also explained that the data as it is does not tell us whether user2 also wants to block user2. My suggestion was to insert a single record on a block event and filter posts by both blocker_id and blocked_id. That would practically achieve a two-way block, but without ambiguity. In that case if we have a symmetrical block, but user1 unblocks user2, then they would still not see

Comment: @ThorstenKettner each-others' posts because user2 would still be blocking user1. It is counter-intuitive and incorrect in my opinion if user2 would automatically block user1. We can avoid showing user1's posts to user2 by checking for both blocked_id and blocker_id in the filter instead of just blocked_id. So the way data is stored is both counter-intuitive and will lead to functional inconsistency. Think about unblocking and all the cases regarding it. If we have user1 and user2, both blocking each-other in the current data model, then when user1 unblocks user2 (so the corresponding

Comment: @ThorstenKettner record is removed), then what should we do with the record which denotes that user2 blocks user1? Should we remove it as well? But what if user2 also wants to block user1? In this case would we unblock user1 for user2 automatically? Or, if we leave user2 blocking user1, then data will be messed up. Also, in our case, when user1 blocks user2 and we will have two records, can user2 unblock user1, removing both records? It should not be possible. But then you will need to compare ids or create dates. So saying that the way data is stored is correct is absolutely wrong in my view.

Comment: I am saying that the data model allows user A to block user B while user B can still read user A posts. This is good. You understand the OP such that they want to always write two mirroring rows, i.e. when user A blocks B, user B blocks A automatically. That wouldn't make much sense. I think you've simply misunderstood. "I don't want that if user1 blocks user2, user2 shouldn't see user1's posts too." just reads a bit confusing. By removing the somewhat double negative, I read it as "I want that if user1 blocks user2, user2 can still see user1's posts."

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you are right, I have edited my answer and will remove my comments from here soon.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it turns that I was right after all, even though you convinced me I was wrong about my understanding of how data is stored by the asker. Subsequently I will leave my comments here as they are.

Comment: Haha, yes. So it was I who misunderstood. When A blocks B it means both A doesn't want to see B's posts and A doesn't want B to see their posts either. `NOT EXISTS` is the best way to solve this, `NOT IN` would be clumsy.

Comment: Thank you. What if Posts/Users are many to many. How would this be extended?

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky basically users can block each-other. If a user can create multiple posts and a post can be created/owned by multiple users, then this relation can be represented by a middle table, like UserPosts(id, user_id, post_id). You would basically join UserPosts with Posts and have the same not exists criteria in the where clause. The logic would be the same, but due to the many-to-many nature user_id would be stored in UserPosts and hence a join with that would be needed.

Comment: @LajosArpad thanks a lot for the reply. I've got that far already, but then after such a join you have multiple rows (assuming a post has multiple users), which you then need to join to the blocks table to see if any of the rows have a user that was blocked by the viewing user. In my case I want to end up with one row for the post, so I then aggregate the rows by post ID and see if any of them have a user that was blocked. If so, then the post should be filtered out. That works but seems too complicated?

Comment: Fixed my problem with better modeling.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky you can group by post if you want a single record for each post in the results.

Answer (score 2):

You want to show all posts, exept those posted by a user that is being blocked by the current user. Use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` to look up blocked users:

```
SELECT * 
FROM post 
WHERE user_id not in (select blocked_id from block where blocker_id = @current_user_id);
```

Comment: I think exists would be a better choice, as it stops at the first match, while not in would compute the whole subselect. Also, I think the schema used by the asker is wrong, as it would lead in ambivalent cases, also, I think it is not very logical to block automatically in the name of the blocked. Nevertheless, your answer appears to be correct, so I upvote it.

Comment: Thank you. `NOT IN` does the same thing as `NOT EXISTS`, so the DBMS should come up with the same execution plan. Whether it looks up rows in a loop or with a hash map or whatever other technique shouldn't bother us. The DB design looks fine to me. A can block B and B can still see A. But OP's explanation on this is somewhat hard to read.

Comment: Do you say that not exists(<your subquery>) will compute the whole subquery in your opinion? Or not in (<your subquery>) will compute just a part of the subquery until the first match is found?

Comment: I am saying that these are two ways to ask for the same data, so the DBMS should execute them both the same. As to the "first" match: there will only be one match in this case. Either user B is blocked by A or not. There should be just one or zero rows for A blocking B in the table. Anyway. finding the optimal way to access the data is the DBMS's job, not ours. Let's just write striaight-forward easy-to-read queries, and the DBMS will have an easy job finding the best execution plan.

Comment: As I explained I did not work much with PostgreSQL, but intuitively it seems that a not in subquery is to be fully computed in order to know what items are we interested in, yet not exists can stop searching at the first match. The implementation might be different though. "there will only be one match in this case". This is a naive assumption. There might be duplicates for whatever reason. "There should be just one or zero rows for A blocking B in the table" Yes, but reality is not always equivalent to what it should be.

Comment: Thank you both for answering my question, this works as I wanted. But I wonder is there a way that I don't have to store two-way block record? I think @LajosArpad talking about this?

Comment: "finding the optimal way to access the data is the DBMS's job, not ours". I disagree. We should aim to write the best possible code. Yeah, we do not need to do micro optimisations, but in this case it is simpler to write the better code.

Comment: @ccoeder you do not need to store both. You can store just one record and when you search for block records, you check for both blocked_id and blocker_id matches.

Comment: @ccoeder if you have user.id = 42 logged in, then you will need to filter out any records where either blocked_id or blocker_id is 42.

Comment: @LajosArpad But what should my <subquery> return in that case? I don't store post_id in my `block` table? <subqery> should return user_id right?

Comment: @ccoeder you just need to change the where in this answer, checking for blocker_id being equal to current_user_id or blocked_id being equal to current_user_id. My answer already deals with this.

Comment: @ccoeder I have edited my answer again, previously I removed some information from there as I thought I misunderstood how you store the data, but your recent comment proves that I understood the way you are storing the data and Thorsten Kettner was wrong about it.

Comment: @ccoeder also, this answer assumes that you store two records for each blocking, which we can see from the where clause. If you switch to use a single row for a single blocking, then this answer is no longer correct, unless it is edited and the where clause is changed to handle both kinds of matching.

Comment: @LajosArpad You are right, I don't want to store two records for one blocking. Let's continue with your sql.

Comment: @ccoeder you can accept this answer as well when Thorsten decides to edit it and improve the where clause.

Comment: @LajosArpad Let's say he improved his sql, what about his subquery, what should subquery return in that case? blocker_id or blocked_id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188142/discussion-between-ccoeder-and-lajos-arpad).

Comment: @ccoeder it should return current user id in the select. We are only interested whether there are any records in the result and since not in is used with that value, its match must be at the selection..